# Datastax PHP Cassandra, getting "No Value or Column for name" error

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax, cql

**Cassandra\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: No value or column for name**

I'm trying to update some old code from YACassandraPDO to Datastax's new PHP extension, and I'm running into some issues. Notably, this error. I can't figure out why or what's wrong.

A parameter numbers match. Is there something drastically different Datastax is doing for prepared statements?

```php
$query  = "UPDATE {$this->keyspace}.visit  USING TTL {$this->ttl}
                SET ip=:ip, browser=:browser, referrer=:ref, terms=:terms
                 ,  url=:url, stime=:stime, etime=:etime
                 , company=:company, isp=:isp, domain=:domain, client_type = :client_type
                 , city=:city, state=:state_cd, postal_cd=:postal, country=:country
                 , country_cd=:country_cd, latitude=:lat, longitude=:long, area_cd=:area_cd
                 , user_id=:user_id
                WHERE visit_dt=:dt AND cid=:cid AND sid=:sid AND pvid=:pvid";
```

The array is:

```
    $params = [
        ':dt'          => new Timestamp(strtotime(date('Y-m-d')), 0),
        ':cid'         => $data['customerId'],
        ':sid'         => $data['sid'],
        ':pvid'        => $data['pvid'],
        // Columns
        ':ip'          => $ip,
        ':browser'     => utf8_encode($data['browser']),
        ':client_type' => utf8_encode($device),
        ':ref'         => utf8_encode($data['referrer']),
        ':terms'       => utf8_encode($terms),
        ':url'         => utf8_encode($data['url']),
        ':stime'       => $data['now'],
        ':etime'       => $data['etime'],
        ':user_id'     => $data['userid'],
        // Geodecode information
        ':company'     => utf8_encode($geo->isp),
        ':domain'      => utf8_encode($geo->domainName),
        ':isp'         => utf8_encode($geo->isp),
        ':city'        => utf8_encode($geo->cityName),
        ':state_cd'    => utf8_encode($geo->regionName),
        ':country'     => utf8_encode($geo->countryName),
        ':country_cd'  => utf8_encode($geo->countryCode),
        ':postal'      => $geo->zipCode,
        ':lat'         => floatval($geo->latitude),
        ':long'        => floatval($geo->longitude),
        ':area_cd'     => $areac
    ];
```

Execution:

```php
        $prep = $this->adapter()->prepare($stmnt);
        $return = $this->adapter()->execute($prep, ['arguments' => $params]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've discovered the issue: the colens. ':key' needs to be just 'key'.

Man, that took just too long to see. All my old bind names were `$stmnt->bindValue(':company', [...]);`; so, it completely escaped my view.